# Tablesorter Custom Parser not working

Tags: jquery, regex, tablesorter

I'm trying to create my own tablesorter parser and it just doesn't work. I generate the table with PHP and my MySQL Database. Here is the problem: In my column 0 is something like 5.98 (50%) and 10.67 (100%) (http://i.epvpimg.com/NsTlb.png). I try to regex out the brackets to sort it properly (the regex works) but Tablesorter just puts the 100% thingy at the bottom :/ You can have a look at the result with debug activated yourself here: http://maxiboether.ma.funpic.de/x264/index2.php

Here is my code:

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>x264 Benchmark</title>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://tablesorter.com/__jquery.tablesorter.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.metadata.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.hoverIntent.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/mbMenu.js"></script>
<script src="js/textext.core.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

<script type="text/javascript">
 $.tablesorter.addParser({ 
        // set a unique id 
        id: 'customFPS', 
        is: function(s) { 
            // return false so this parser is not auto detected 
            return false; 
        }, 
        format: function(s) { 
            // format your data for normalization 
             return $.tablesorter.formatFloat(s.replace(/ *\([^)]*\) */g, ""));

        }, 
        // set type, either numeric or text 
        type: 'numeric' 
    }); 
$(document).ready(function() 
    { 
        $("#keywords").tablesorter({ 
        // enable debug mode 
        debug: true 
        }); 
        $("#keywords").tablesorter({
            headers: {
                0: {sorter:'customFPS'}
            }
        }); 
        $("#keywords").tablesorter({
            sortList: [[0,1]]
        }); 


    } 
); 

</script>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Sincerely,

Mayesters

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by letting Tablesorter decide if this is a FPS column!

My code now is:

```
 $.tablesorter.addParser({ 
        // set a unique id 
        id: 'customFPS', 
        is: function(s) { 
            // return false so this parser is not auto detected 
            return s.match(new RegExp(/ *\([^)]*\) */g));
        }, 
        format: function(s) { 
            // format your data for normalization 
             return $.tablesorter.formatFloat(parseFloat(s.replace(/ *\([^)]*\) */g, "")));

        }, 
        // set type, either numeric or text 
        type: 'numeric' 
    });
```

Comment: I'm glad you found an answer, but the actual problem is that tablesorter is being initialized three times. Look at [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/abkNM/), it shows how to add multiple options.